# Change time intervals in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, time

I need to change the time intervals in this javascript function after multiples of 3 and 5, but this is not happening.
What's wrong?
To do this, it is better to use 'setInterval' or 'setTimeout'?
Thank you!

```
//index.js
var countx = 1;
var multiplox = 2500;

function intervalFunc() {
   console.log('Cant stop me now! ', countx, multiplox);

   if (countx % 3 === 0) {
      const timeoutObj = setTimeout(() => {
         console.log('timeout beyond time 3');
      }, 1500);
   }
   if (countx % 5 === 0) {
      const timeoutObj = setTimeout(() => {
         console.log('timeout beyond time 5');
      }, 20000);
   }
   countx++;

}
setInterval(intervalFunc, 4000);
```

Comment: Is `countx` changing values? Might be better to pass it as a parameter

Comment: So what exactly needs to change? The time in the interval (`4000`), the time in the first 'if' statement (`1500`), or the time in the second 'if' statement (`20000`)???... The desired outcome is not very clear here.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

```
var countx = 1;
var multiplox = 2500;
var interv;
function intervalFunc() {
    console.log('Cant stop me now! ', countx, multiplox);

    if (countx % 3 === 0){
            console.log('timeout beyond time 3');
            clearInterval(interv);
            interv = setInterval(intervalFunc, 1500);
    }
    if (countx % 5 === 0){
            console.log('timeout beyond time 5')
            clearInterval(interv);
            interv = setInterval(intervalFunc, 20000);
    }
    countx ++;

}
interv = setInterval(intervalFunc, 4000);
```

I don't know if this is what you need. But if you what to change the interval Timeout you can do it like this!

What it does is it will start with a timeout of 4000 and after every 3 time it will change to 1500 and after every 5 time it will change to 20000.
But I don't know why you have this multiplox variable?

Comment: Very thanks
The 'var multiplox'  is unnecessary, I forgot to remove it.
Your answer solved my problem.

Comment: @MikailhP good ;-). If this solved your problem. Please mark my answer with solved